Можно ли в Swing задать UI пользовательскому компоненту?
Сейчас я изучаю pluggable LAF в Swing. У меня есть компонент HButton, наследующий кнопку, но немного расширяющий её функциональность. Было бы неплохо задать для неё отдельный UI по умолчанию.
Псевдокод:
UIManager.put("HButtonUI",MyHButtonUI.class.getName());

Можно ли подобное осуществить?
